# How can i pass multiple dates and enable only between selected dates and disable other than the selected dates in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd, daterangepicker

```
const disableNotRangeDate = current =>
state.tourSeasonalDates.some(date =>
  !current.isBetween(moment(date['startRange']), moment(date['endRange'])) 
);

{state.nonOperationalDates.map(task => (
          <DateRangeComponent
            onClickMinusButton={() => deleteNonOperationalDateRow(task)}
            seasonKey={task.index}
            // onChange={onChangeTourSeasonalDates(task)}
            // ranges={current=>enabledRangeDate(current)}
            disabledDate={current => disableNotRangeDate(current)}
          />
        ))}
```

[image]

//Here while selecting single date i am able to disable other than the selected date but while selecting multiple dates it disables all the dates. But i want it to make able to only select the date between the above selected date i.e. enable the above selected date range and disable other than the selected date range. How can i do that?

Comment: which date range picker are you using?

Comment: I am using RangePicker of antd library. i.e.      <RangePicker style={{ padding: 5 }} onChange={onChange} key={seasonKey} disabledDate={disabledDate}/>

Comment: I am having the same requirements, can you tell me what you did